# Cross Compiling on mac os x

Tags: c

How do i compile my c programs on mac os x, so they work on linux oses?, i've searched google for this but i seam to only get results the other way around?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775267/how-to-cross-compile-from-mac-os-x-to-linux-x86, another closed duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060417/compile-c-program-on-mac-to-run-on-linux/3060496#3060496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to run a virtual Linux on your Mac? The reason why there are only results for the other way round is because it's not as easy to virtualise OS X in Linux.