# compiling for other platforms

Tags: c++, linux, macos, compilation, multiplatform

is it possible to compile (under mac os x using netbeans) C++ code for linux architectures?

Comment: It can be done without NetBeans. Not sure it can be done *with* NetBeans though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775267/how-to-cross-compile-from-mac-os-x-to-linux-x86, and if you don't want to virtualize, you can follow the links from the answer to : http://www.nongnu.org/thug/cross.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's called cross-compiling. For instructions how to build and use cross-compiler go [here](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-ARM-cross-compiling-howto.html).