# Creating linux cross compiler running on mac 10.6

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I have mac snowleopard 10.6 but i develop lots of programs (in C & C++) for linux hosts.
I've tried compiling them under a ubuntu linux vm in virtualbox but the VM isn't the same performance as my mac and is very hard to keep swapping files between.

I've read: http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php about the "i386-Linux Binaries for Intel" and installed the binary the author of that wiki made and it works but it is an old version of gcc that came with that package.
I tried compiling a cross compiler using his script but it fails because my mac does not have a case sensitive file system.

Can anyone suggest how to create a cross compiler on a mac for i386 linux?

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775267/how-to-cross-compile-from-mac-os-x-to-linux-x86 might help

Comment: I already have an older cross compiler for linux on my mac. if i compiled a newer one like usual but set the compiler for the new one to the older one. will that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create case-sensitive workspace. The following documents might help.

[Get Android Source Code](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) "Creating a case sensitive disk image"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an issue with virtualbox. I am still using Leopard, have a Fedora 13 VM with Parallels and performance is absolutely fine. I use TextMate for editing, mount the source directory in the VM and compile using gcc in the normal way, no hassle with copying files about at all.

Sometimes I have to fire up another VM with an older version of Fedora and CLI performance is still fine on both VMs and OS X. Console speed (on the VM) can be a bit slow but I only ever have to use that if I have locked myself out whilst playing about with iptables.